# Pebble.JS: Acces a menu object created in a function

Tags: javascript, function, pebble-js

**In breef:**

I have created a menu object in a function, but I cannot access that menu object in the main script.

**The full explanation:**

In the function createMyMenu() I do create a menu object with some items and the menu is shown. This works fine and the user can move up/down in the menu by using the buttons on the Pebble smartwatch.

Problem is that the user cannot select any items, just navigate in the menu.

If I create the menu object in the main script, I (of course) works just fine, but if I create the menu object in a function, the user can not select any menu item.

Question: How can I create a menu in a function and then use that menu object in the main script the same way as if the menu was created in the main script?

The code:

```
function createMyMenu()
{
// Some code to create the menu object myMenu. Works fine.
  myMenu.show();  // Also works fine, the menu and it contents are displayed.
  return myMenu; // No errors
}
```

And the script

```
mainMenu = createMyMenu(); // Create the menu.
mainMenu.on('select', function(e) // This does not seem to be executed. 
{
  // Code to execute when the user selects a menu item.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, så here is some working code:

```
var UI = require('ui');

function createMyMenu()
{
// Some code to create the menu object myMenu. Works fine.
var myMenu = new UI.Menu({
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  textColor: 'white',
  highlightBackgroundColor: 'white',
  highlightTextColor: 'black',
  sections: [{
    title: 'My Menu',
    items: [{
      title: 'First Item',
      subtitle: 'first subtitle'
    }, { 
      title: 'second Item',
      subtitle: 'Second subtitle'
    }, {
      title: 'Third Item',
      subtitle: 'Third subtitle'
    }]
  }]
}); 

 myMenu.show();  // Also works fine, the menu and it contents are displayed.
  return myMenu; // No errors
}

//***** THE SCRIPT ******

var mainMenu = createMyMenu(); // Create the menu.
mainMenu.on('select', function(e) // This does not seem to be executed. 
{
  // Code to execute when the user selects a menu item.
    console.log('Button pressed');
    console.log('Selected item #' + e.itemIndex + ' of section #' + e.sectionIndex);
  console.log('The item is titled "' + e.item.title + '"');
});
```